# Проброс эвента из глубин классов в форму

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Добрый вечер. Небольшой вопрос по архитектуре приложения, в данном случае, на C# (.NET 2.0, версии старше не предлагать).

Основное окно программы создает класс **A**. Класс **A**, внутри себя, создает *private* класс **B**. Внутри класса **B**, есть *private* **BackgroundWorker**, который генерит событие **RunWorkerCompleted**

Задача - когда наступает это событие, на форме должен вызываться мой обработчик **OnMessageReceived**. То есть, мне как то нужно подписаться из формы на событие, которое так глубоко закопано и, более того, еще и сокрыто.

Более того, я хочу создать достаточно гибкую архитектуру, чтобы сегодня это работало в WinForms, завтра в WPF, а послезавтра - оформить класс **A** как сборку. То есть, форма тут вообще для примера, важно, что должен вызываться мой обработчик.

Конечно, в голову приходят варианты вроде создания get-свойств в классах **A**, **B**, которые будут возвращать эвент для возможности на него подписаться. Или создания, опять таки, во всех классах set-свойств, для проброса делегата с нужной мне функцией.

Но хочется узнать, как это сделать правильно. Как, в условиях инкапсуляции, пробрасывать переменные/ссылки через несколько классов, не теряя при этом гибкость архитектуры?

**И есть ли книжки, где описаны подобные моменты и наилучшие практики? Или же только свои шишки набивать?)**

**[UPD]** *(текст выше немного изменен, убрал лишние классы, суть прежняя)*
.NET 2.0 обусловлен энтерпрайзом. Там все очень долго и медленно меняется. Так что, только 2.0, только хардкор.

Теперь о дизайне. На самом деле, программа скорее тренировочная. Представляет из себя отправку и принятие сообщений (далее - "чат") по RS232, используя класс **SerialPort**.

В основном окне создается основной класс чата (**А**), чтобы не писать логику в формочках.

Далее, класс чата, в том числе, создает класс для принятия сообщений (**B**).
Помимо этого, создается класс для их формирования и отправки, подключения/отключения к порту, то есть, придерживаюсь принципа "Один класс - одна задача".

Но вернемся к нашей иерархии. Внутри класса принятия сообщений **B** создается потоковый класс **C** с одним методом, который и передается в **BackgroundWorker**. Этот класс нужен для передачи большого числа параметров в поток, [подробнее на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wkays279.aspx).

Вот и получается, что внутри форммы - класс, внутри класса - другой класс, а внутри другого класса - **BackgroundWorker** с нужным мне эвентом.

Comment: C# 2.0? Прекратите насиловать труп.

Comment: Скорее всего, это Bad design. Чем обусловлена иерархия классов A->B->C->D?

Comment: Вот-вот, ваш дизайн плох. Для начала: у вас не должно быть в классе `A` события `OnWorkerComplete`, никому не интересно, что какая-то внутренняя операция на сегодняшний день реализуется `BackgroundWorker`'ом. Выносите наружу семантику, а не детали реализации. Что класс `А` хочет сказать миру, когда `BackgroundWorker` добежит до конца?

Comment: Уточнил задачу. Да, пример с OnWorkerComplete не очень хороший, пусть это будет нейтральный OnMessageReceived. Не важно. Важно, что это событие происходит глубоко внизу, а мне, наверху, нужно уведомить пользователя.

Comment: То есть, класс формы содержит какой-то класс MyChatProgram, в который завернут класс ChatClient, который скрывает класс MessageSender (хотя он не просто sender, а еще и соединяться умеет). И там внутри еще что-то. Дизайн плохой.

Comment: Соединяться умеет ChatConnector внутри ChatClient. Но, в целом, да. А как правильно? И, повторю вопрос из топика, где можно почитать про правильную архитектуру? Вряд ли в паттернах, там все более глобально.

Comment: Смотрите. Во-первых, окончание работы BW совсем не означает a priori, что данные готовы: может понадобиться пост-обработка в `B`. Кроме того, возможно, `B` захочет отправить сообщение в совсем другом потоке. Так что (1) придумайте хорошее название для `B` и для события, которое он выставляет окружающему миру; (2) `A` пусть подписывается на это событие, возможно обновляет своё состояние, и при подходящих условиях генерирует другое событие. Если завтра `B` перестанет генерировать событие, об этом никто и не узнает (кроме класса `A`, но ему и положено об этом знать).

Comment: Ну, по-большому счету, к чтению про правильную архитектуру вы уже приступили :)

Заверните все, что относится к клиенту, в ChatClient. ChatConnector не нужен.

Класс MyChatProgram вынесите на самый верний уровень. ChatClient можно вынести туда же, а можно поместить в какой-нибудь отдельный неймспейс вроде DeniDoman.Net (если имя вашего корневого неймспейса - DeniDoman).

Насчет того, что хорошо почитать - "Совершенный код" МакКоннелла.

Comment: @VladD, понятно, то есть, использовать цепочку событий. Если б был еще один уровень вложенности, то события было бы 3. Еще один - 4. 

@Flammable, в данном случае, это было бы правильно. Просто ведь это мое приложение - тысячастрочник. Но ведь бывают и более большие, где подобная вложенность не является чем-то ненормальным (на 3-4 уровня, не больше). В этом случае, все в один класс не засунешь, а пробросить эвент надо. И как поступить? Вот, @VladD советует на каждом уровне создавать по эвенту и пробрасывать через такую цепочку. Вы согласны?

Comment: Собственно, тут я скорее тренируюсь, чтобы в будущем, когда придется писать что-то большее, не налажать. Поэтому и применяю заведомо избыточные техники к столь маленькой утилитке. 

Хочется верить, что после прочтения "Совершенного кода" у меня станет получше с разработкой архитектуры. Не той, которая на уровне паттернов, а более низкоуровневой, что ли, но все же архитектуры. Может, у нее и свое название есть, не знаю.

Comment: @DeniDoman: для такой простой задачи 4 -- слишком большое количество уровней вложенности. А для сложной задачи сколько надо, столько надо. Не дело же внешним уровням вообще знать о существовании внутренних, правда? И я не советую на каждом уровне обязательно иметь event, как между собой общается класс и его внутренности -- на каждом уровне решать по отдельности. Но внутренние события не имеют права быть видимыми сверху, иначе возможностей для расширения не останется. (Предположим, что каждый уровень хочет что-то добавить новое к данным, полученным от предыдущего уровня -- как тогда?)

Comment: @DeniDoman: кстати, если бы я писал проект, я бы сделал не event `OnMessageReceived`, а попробовал бы Rx extensions, и выставил наружу `IObservable<IMessage>`. Не знаю, доступны ли Rx ext. под 2.0, всё-таки поддержка функционального стиля программирования в Java-образном C# 2.0 не очень.

Comment: > В этом случае, все в один класс не засунешь, а пробросить эвент надо.

У серьезных пацанов таких проблем почти не возникает. Потому что внешним классам ничего не нужно знать о том, сколько байтов записал в поток какой-то менеджер пакетов, завернутый еще несколько раз. В редких случаях может случиться, что такое нужно. Тогда соответствующее поле добавляется во все классы-обертки до тех пор, пока оно не будет доступно из нужного скопа.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо поднимать именно событие воркера.
При возникновении собтия воркера класс B должен кинуть свое событие со своими аргументами. В ответ на это событие класс А должен кинуть свое событие. И вот на событие класса А уже должна подписаться форма своим обработчиком. По сути, классы А, В и воркер - это разные уровни абстракции, и они не должны протекать друг в друга. Только так ваша архитектура будет достаточно гибкой, позволит добавлять постобработку событий на каждом уровне или безболезненно менять уровни целиком.
То есть, форма не должна ничего знать о событиях воркера. Форма вообще не должна знать о существовании какого-то там воркера.